# Flutter : How to make an http stream for StreamBuilder

Tags: http, flutter, stream, future, stream-builder

#### Hello

I'm trying to make my first social app with Flutter and I'm stuck.
I would like to get my messages (in a conversasion between tow users) from my api.
Not a probleme when I use Future and Future Builder, but I would like the message list to update when a new message is send !

I found we can achieve it with stream, but every time I try to convert my Future In Stream, it still work, but just as if it was a Future (it never upadate on new message).

here I a simplified part of my code :

```dart
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final Conv conv;
  final User otherUser;

  const Test({Key key, this.conv, this.otherUser}) : super(key: key);
  
  

  Stream<List<Message>> messageFlow(String convId) {
    return Stream.fromFuture(getMessages(convId));
  }

  Future<List<Message>> getMessages(String convId) async {
    var data = await http
        .post(MyApiUrl, headers: <String, String>{}, body: <String, String>{
      "someParam": "param",
      "id": convId,
    });
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<Message> messages = [];
    for (var m in jsonData) {
      Message message = Message.fromJson(m);
      messages.add(message);
    }
    return messages;
  }


  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: messageFlow(conv.id),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Loading'),
              ),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
              reverse: true,
              controller: _messagesListController,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Message message = snapshot.data[index];
                var isMe = message.owner == otherUser.id ? false : true;
                return _buildMessage(message, isMe);
              });
        });
  }
}
```

it would be so nice if you could help me !

Comment: Converting a `Future` to a `Stream` is essentially the same as just using a `Future` as you have discovered. You need to make your own `Stream` that periodically performs your existing `Future`. Look at the "Creating a Stream from Scratch" section of [this](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not able to replicate your sample code, but here how I understood your question.

Let's first define the difference about `Future` and `Streams`:

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59610814/8342742)

> A **Future** is like the token with a number on it that they give you when
> you order takeout; you made the request, but the result is not yet
> ready but you have a placeholder. And when the result is ready, you
> get a callback (the digital board above the takeout counter shows your
> number or they shout it out) - you can now go in and grab your food
> (the result) to take out.
>
> A **Stream** is like that belt carrying little sushi bowls. By sitting
> down at that table, you've "subscribed" to the stream. You don't know
> when the next sushi boat will arrive - but when the chef (message
> source) places it in the stream (belt), then the subscribers will
> receive it. The important thing to note is that they arrive
> asynchronously (you have no idea when the next boat/message will come)
> but they will arrive in sequence (i.e., if the chef puts three types
> of sushi on the belt, in some order -- you will see them come by you
> in that same order)

Now here is an example of how you can [create your own stream from scratch](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  // 1st approach
  final StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
 
  addData()async{
    for(int i = 1; i<= 10; i++) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

      _streamController.sink.add(i);
    }
  }

  // 2nd approach
  // This approach will prevent some approach of memory leaks
  Stream<int> numberStream() async*{
    for(int i = 1; i<= 10; i++) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

      yield i;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _streamController.close();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    addData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text("Stream"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: numberStream().map((number) => "number $number"),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasError)
                return Text("hey there is some error");
              else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              return Text("${snapshot.data}", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,);
            },
          )
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

[image]

You can also check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44788660/8342742) for some references.

Here, I tweaked the sample in the SO post above to create a mini simple chat server to show how the messages updates.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Server {
  StreamController<String> _controller = new StreamController.broadcast();
  void simulateMessage(String message) {
    _controller.add(message);
  }

  Stream get messages => _controller.stream;
}

final server = new Server();

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => new _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<String> _messages = <String>[];
  StreamSubscription<String> _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _subscription = server.messages.listen((message) async => setState(() {
          _messages.add(message);
        }));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display2;
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Sample App'),
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        children: _messages.map((String message) {
          return new Card(
            child: new Container(
              height: 100.0,
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text(message, style: textStyle),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          new FloatingActionButton(
            child: new Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
            onPressed: () {
              // simulate a message arriving
              server.simulateMessage('Hello World');
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          new FloatingActionButton(
            child: new Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
            onPressed: () {
              // simulate a message arriving
              server.simulateMessage('Hi Flutter');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new SampleApp());
}
```

[image]

And here are some tutorials for better references:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQBpOIHE4eE
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc

Answer (score 3):

this works for me

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as HTTP;

class PeriodicRequester extends StatelessWidget {
Stream<http.Response> getRandomNumberFact() async* {
yield* Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (_) {
  return http.get("http://numbersapi.com/random/");
}).asyncMap((event) async => await event);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<http.Response>(
  stream: getRandomNumberFact(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
      ? Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.body))
      : CircularProgressIndicator(),
);
}
}
```