# How to read HTTP text response as a stream in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, http

My app's backend server gives text response as stream.

Server (node.js): `response.write(chunk);`

I want to display the text immediately as the text is being received in chunks.
Like this:

```
String text = '';
http.getStream(uri, (chunk) {
    setState() {
        text = text + chunk;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use Stream.fromFuture to get the updated value, here the link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/Stream.fromFuture.html

Comment: @WilsonToribio Stream.fromFuture fires onData() only once. But I want chunks immediately as the server sends.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433903/flutter-how-to-make-an-http-stream-for-streambuilder

Comment: This answer is irrelevant. I want to show it like a ChatGPT response. Big text will be produced by the server and sent in chunks while producing.

Comment: If you are streaming data from the server it might be that you are using some sort of socket server, so there are packages in Flutter for socket listening for the specific socket server you are using.